Numerical Solution of Self-Consistent Gap Equation with Singularities in $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$ , $Y_1$ and $Y_2$
I am working on calculating the gap function $ |\Delta| $ as a function of energy in a superconductor. The self-consistent equation I am using is:
$
\frac{1}{V} = \frac{1}{2D} \int_{-D}^{+D} N(x)\left[ \beta_1 \tanh \left( \frac{Y_1}{2T} \right) + \beta_2 \tanh \left( \frac{Y_2}{2T} \right) \right] dx,
$
$N(x)$ is something like Density of states and I have data for that
where:
$
\beta_1 = \frac{Y_1^2 - \bar{x}^2}{2Y_1(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2)}, \quad \beta_2 = \frac{Y_2^2 - \bar{x}^2}{2Y_2(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2)},
$
and:
$
Y_{1,2}^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left[x_1^2 + \bar{\bar{x}}_1^2 + |\Delta|^2 \pm \sqrt{(x_1^2 + \bar{\bar{x}}_1^2 + |\Delta|^2)^2 - 4(x_1^2 \bar{x}_1^2 + |\Delta|^2 \bar{\bar{x}}_1^2)} \right].
$
Here, $ x_1, \bar{x}_1, \bar{\bar{x}}_1, \bar{x}$, and $ |\Delta| $ are functions of $x $, and $ V $ is the interaction strength. The energy range is $ -D \leq x \leq D $, and $ T $ is the temperature.
$x_1 = x - \mu$
$\bar{x_1} = x_1 + U$
$\bar{\bar{x_1}} = x_1 + (1 - \rho) U$
My goal is to numerically compute $ |\Delta| $ as a function of $ x $ by solving this equation self-consistently.
We have singularities in $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $Y_1$, and $Y_2$, and I believe there may be problems with integrating these functions.
The real part of them is :


and the imaginary part is :


These singularities seem to be problematic, especially in the context of numerical integration. I am uncertain how to handle these singularities in the numerical solution process. Can anyone suggest strategies for dealing with such singularities in this context, or recommend numerical methods for integrating these functions despite the singularities?
my python code :

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath

# Given functions
def beta1(Y1, Y2, x_barbar):
    return (Y1**2 - x_barbar**2) / (2 * Y1 * (Y1**2 - Y2**2))

def beta2(Y1, Y2, x_barbar):
    return (Y2**2 - x_barbar**2) / (2 * Y2 * (Y1**2 - Y2**2))

def Y_squares(x, Delta, mu, U, rho):
    x1 = x - mu
    x_bar = x1 + U
    x_barbar = x1 + (1 - rho) * U
    term = x1**2 + x_barbar**2 + Delta**2
    root_term = cmath.sqrt(term**2 - 4 * (x1**2 * x_bar**2 + Delta**2 * x_barbar**2))
    Y1_sq = 0.5 * (term + root_term)
    Y2_sq = 0.5 * (term - root_term)
    return cmath.sqrt(Y1_sq), cmath.sqrt(Y2_sq)

# Parameters (adjust these based on your case)
mu = 0
U = 1
rho = 0.5

# Choose a specific value of Delta
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
Delta = 0.1   # Example: Set Delta to a specific value, like 0.1

# Define the range of x values
x_values = np.linspace(-1, 1, 400)

# Initialize lists to store the results
Y1_values = []
Y2_values = []
beta1_values = []
beta2_values = []

# Loop over x to compute Y1, Y2, beta1, and beta2 for the chosen Delta
for x in x_values:
    Y1, Y2 = Y_squares(x, Delta, mu, U, rho)
    Y1_values.append(Y1)
    Y2_values.append(Y2)
    x_bar = x - mu + U
    try:
        beta1_values.append(beta1(Y1, Y2, x_bar))
        beta2_values.append(beta2(Y1, Y2, x_bar))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        beta1_values.append(np.inf)  # Handle singularity where division by zero occurs
        beta2_values.append(np.inf)

# Convert lists to arrays for easy plotting
Y1_values = np.array(Y1_values, dtype = 'complex_')
Y2_values = np.array(Y2_values, dtype = 'complex_')
beta1_values = np.array(beta1_values, dtype = 'complex_')
beta2_values = np.array(beta2_values, dtype = 'complex_')

# Smooth beta1 and beta2
smoothed_beta1 = savgol_filter(beta1_values, 11, 3) # Increased window size
smoothed_beta2 = savgol_filter(beta2_values, 11, 3)
# Plotting the results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))

# Plot Y1 and Y2
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(x_values, Y1_values.imag, label='Y1')  # Only plot real part
plt.plot(x_values, Y2_values.imag, label='Y2', linestyle='--')
plt.title(f'Y1 and Y2 vs x for Delta={Delta}')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Y1, Y2')
plt.legend()

# Plot beta1 and beta2
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(x_values, beta1_values.imag, label='beta1')
plt.plot(x_values, beta2_values.imag, label='beta2', linestyle='--')
plt.title(f'beta1 and beta2 vs x for Delta={Delta}')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('beta1, beta2')
plt.legend()

# Show the plots
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

